# Prove that a question that got solved by at least 13 students exists

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem:**
Let there be 20 students which took part in an exam.

- The exam consist of 4 questions.
- Each student solved at least 2 questions
- 5 students solved all 4 question.

Show that there exists such question that got solved by at least 13 students.

**My attempt:**
So 5 students solved all 4 question,
then we got 15 students left that solved at least 2 questions. If it would be the minimum, that the remaining students all solved only 2 questions we can divide them into two groups. A group `X` that solved questions 1) and 2) and a group `Y` that solved questions 3) and 4)

Because in either group `X` or `Y` there will be 8 students and in the other one 7, we proved that there exists a question that got solved by at least 13 students.

**Question:** Is my reasoning valid? Especially the part where I divide the remaining students into two groups I'm not so sure about.

Is it possible to introduce some math formalism so that it's not so much text?

Comment: No.  Why divide into X that solved questions 1 and 2, and Y that solved 3 and 4?  What if someone solved 1 and 3?  or 2 and 4?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  thought that I can simplify it to that, because if someone solved other combination of questions I could like take "half of one person" to group X and the other half to Y. But still it would add to the 7 and 8 numbers.

Comment: You can assume that without loss of generality, students succedded the most for question 1. Now what happens if only 7 of these 15 students succedded in question 1? Is there a contradiction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let there be no question that was solved by $13$ students or more. Then each question is solved by $12$ students at most. Since there are $4$ questions there are at most $48$ solutions.

At the same time $5$ students solved all $4$ questions which gives $20$ solutions. And the rest $15$ students solved at least $2$ questions each. So there are at least $20+15 \cdot 2 = 50$ solutions. We got contradiction, so our suggestion was false. Therefore there is a question solved by $13$ students or more.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of correct problem solutions is $5 \cdot 4 = 20$ for the first five students, and $15 \cdot 2 = 30$ for the other students, for a total of $50$ solutions among four questions.  That's 12.5 correct solutions per problem (on average).  You can't have all four problems have 12 correct solutions, so at least one question has 13 correct solutions.